# How do I resolve the error "(\Tahoma8)You can install Virtual Machine Additions only on a valid virtual machine..."?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a virtual machine that I have migrated from Virtual Server 2005 R2 over to Hyper V R2 server but I am unable to remove the virtual machine additions. When I try to remove them I get the following error:

"(\Tahoma8)You can install Virtual Machine Additions only on a valid virtual machine that is running a supported guest operating system"

followed by a

Fatal Error

How do I remove these virtual machine additions from the VM while it is running under Hyper V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue with Virtual Server virtual machines.  There is a bug that stops the virtual machine additions from being uninstalled when the virtual machine is migrated to another platfom.

That said - this bug was fixed in Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1.

The painful part is that to fix this you will need to:

1. Setup a server running Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1
2. Move the virtual machine onto this server
3. Update the virtual machine additions (or alternatively - just uninstall them there)
4. Move the virtual machine back to Hyper-V

You can get the installer for Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bc49c7c8-4840-4e67-8dc4-1e6e218acce4

This acts as both an upgrade and a stand-alone installer (so if you need to setup a new server to do this - you do not need to install Virtual Server 2005 R2 before installing Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1).

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: I was able to bring the VM back up under the original Virtual Server 2005 environment and uninstall the virtual machine additions. I have to believe there is another way to do this but for now this is as good as it gets. Thanks

Comment: You can also use Virtual PC, but that's really not much more convenient.